# Get Row Count in SQLAlchemy Bulk Operations

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to get the number of rows affected as a result of executing     `session.bulk_insert_mappings()` and `session.bulk_update_mappings()`?

I have seen that you can use `ResultProxy.rowcount` to get this number with `connection.execute()`, but how does it work with these bulk operations?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `bulk_insert_mappings` and `bulk_update_mappings` do not return the number of rows created/updated.

If your update is the same for all the objects (for example increasing some int field by 1) you could use this:
`updatedCount = session.query(People).filter(People.name == "Nadav").upadte({People.age: People.age + 1)`